# Use of ! in if(!$db)

Tags: php

I would like to know the use/meaning of `!` in `if(!$db)`. If it were to be `if($db)` (without the exclamation mark), I'll understand.

I've tried searching Google and PHP.net for it but got nothing. Please can someone help me?

Here's the code:

```
if(!$db)

die("Database not configured.");

if(!mysql_select_db("$dbname",$db))

die("No database selected.");
```

Comment: You need to edit your question and show the code you're talking about.

Comment: The expression `!$var` can be thought of as `$var == false`.

Comment: See also: [logical operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).

Comment: Simply said and in layman's terms: It reads as "**if** there is `no` database connection established, stop the process and show the error message `Database not configured.`". Then it reads as "**if** there is `no` database selected, then show the error message `No database selected.`" - The `no` part is the `!` exclamation mark. `die()` means `stop` the process.

Comment: And this `if(!mysql_select_db("$dbname",$db))` should not have any quotes in it. Therefore it should read as `if(!mysql_select_db($dbname,$db))`

Answer (score 1):

The `!` sign negates an expression. Without seeing any of the actual code, we can only guess what your program does. I suspect that the code you are looking at tries to open a connection to a database. If the connection fails, the expression `!$db` will be `true` (`$db` would evaluate to `false`). This probably prompts the code to handle the exceptions and print and error statement etc.

Comment: Edited. I've inserted the code

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour of that operator is described [here in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).

It yields TRUE if the expression was not TRUE and vice-versa.

In this particular case you could achieve the same thing as:

```
mysql_connect( ... ) or die("Database not configured.");
mysql_select_db("$dbname",$db) or die("No database selected.");
```

Btw, you shouldn't use `mysql_` functions anymore; consider switching to either mysqli or PDO.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking me.

Comment: @Fred, the db contains the dbname and dbuser

Comment: *"I would like to know the use/meaning of ! in if(!$db). If it were to be if($db) (without the exclamation mark), I'll understand."* - [`Your question has been answered`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21770302/use-of-in-ifdb#comment32934748_21770302) – @Inyavic